# Why after running docker containers a website prints a 403 forbidden nginx error?

Tags: docker, nginx

I've built image and ran the containers in docker and checked them with `docker ps`. All the containers are running.

I also edited `/etc/hosts/` file and added my server name like:

`127.0.0.1   myServerName`

But when I try to request to the server, I got a `403 Forbidden nginx/1.15.3` error.

Could someone give any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your nginx.conf as well your Dockerfile?

Comment: You're quite likely uploading your files to a folder that's different from the one specified in the nginx config file. If this isn't enough for you to troubleshoot, you can post the files as @rahoogan suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `/etc/hosts` configuration is essential. But I suggest you try to add `-p` flag when executing `docker run`. Just like below:

```
docker run -d --name=nginx -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx:latest
```

After making sure the nginx container is running, query `localhost:80` again.